# How do you do string replacement in MSBuild 4.0?

Tags: string, msbuild, replace

After inputting an ItemGroup containing a list of file names, I'm trying to swap the extensions to something different.  For example, I want file.foo converted to file.bar.  Is this possible within MSBuild?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have an item group containing the files for which you want to change the name, just use that as input to a Copy or Move task and modify its metadata. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx) is a list of common item metadata.

```
<!-- The list of .foo files is in the ItemGroup myFiles -->
<Copy SourceFiles="@(myFiles)" DestinationFiles="%(myFiles.Filename).bar" />
```

Metadata is accessed by %(/varName/./metadata/). In this example, I am setting the extension to whatever I want by only including the original Filename metadata in the output.